# How to configure Apache Airflow with Celery to run concurrent tasks?

Tags: airflow

I am interested in this use case for my proof of concept, where i read from a file containing a huge list of ids and i want to process this ids as such func(id) concurrently.
Is it possible to configure airflow with CeleryExecutors to achieve this?

I saw this link :-
[Running more than 32 concurrent tasks in Apache Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640246/running-more-than-32-concurrent-tasks-in-apache-airflow)

But what if the number of ids are unknown and could be anywhere from 10,000 or even 100,000 and i want to process them around 500-1000 at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow can execute tasks in parallel, and it can use Celery to achieve this. Everything else is up to you to implement however you see fit, there are no specifics related to Airflow/Celery regarding your intended use. 
In the end, if all you care about is paralleling your work and don't care much about other Airflow features, you could be better off using Celery alone.

There are many different ways to go about this, but here is some food for though to get you started:

- Airflow tasks should be as "dumb" as possible, i.e. take an input, process it and store the output. Don't put your file-splitting logic here. You can have a dedicated DAG for that if needed. For example, you can have a DAG which reads the input file and chunks it up via some logic, then store it somewhere for tasks to pick up (convenient file structure, message queue, db, etc.)
- Decide on a place for your input data such that tasks can easily pick up a limited amount of input. For example, if you're using a file structure, where one chunk to be processed is a single file, a task can get read a single file and remove it. Repeat until no chunks/files are left. Same goes for any other way, e.g. if using a message queue you can consume the chunks. Make sure you have that original DAG ready to split up the input file into chunks again if needed. You are free to make this as simple or as complex as you want.
- Watch out for idempotency, e.g. make sure your process can be repeated without side-effects. If you lose data in some step, you can just restart everything without issues.